# On the current memory retain limits for the coldboot attack (2020)

Tags: attack

ColdBoot attack is introduced by Halderman et. al in 2009

- [Lest we remember: cold-boot attacks on encryption keys](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec08/tech/full_papers/halderman/halderman.pdf)

In their articles, they represent experimented that

> We found that the dimensions of the decay curves varied considerably between machines, with the fastest exhibiting complete data loss in approximately 2.5 seconds and the slowest taking an
> average of 35 seconds.

Currently, Wikipedia on the [Cold Boot attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cold_boot_attack&oldid=990860411) article states that

> Depending on temperature and environmental conditions, memory modules can potentially retain, at least, some data for up to 90 minutes after power loss

and give a reference to this article!;

- [Cold Boot Attack on Cell Phones](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326211565) by Bali in July 2018

A quick look at the article means that this is not a reliable source for this claim.

- Does this claim true? Since it is huge jumping from seconds to hours.
- Are there any reliable sources for the actual timings?

Comment: I have no info on this, or practice of cold boot attack. But my limited understanding is that a common cold boot attack physically resets the CPU (e.g. from sleep mode, without a full power down) and then try to run its code as fast as possible. With enough control on the boot sequence, that can be well under 1s. Or perhaps the code runs later, but the boot sequence/BIOS actually re-enabled DRAM refresh within 1s (the hard part might become preventing that the DRAM gets erased). Or perhaps some call "cold boot attack" a mere examination of the hibernation hard disk file.

Comment: @fgrieu there are, special coolers to increase the attack time, though that is not the point, one needs either boot with a special live OS or take out the RAM into special hardware to copy the current state.

Comment: I've heard of the cooler thing, and the physics of leakage is such that it works. But I always wondered how common it is that [this stunt](https://youtube.com/watch?v=E6gzVVjW4yY) is pulled. [Data sheets of an IC manufacturer](https://google.com/search?q=Refresh+period+site%3Amicron.com) show refresh periods on the tune of 64ms, so I guess a large fraction of cells keep data much longer than that; but 2.5s seems a lot for these modern ICs. Again, I'm not sure actual attacks really power down the DRAM for long, or at all. [Electronics-SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) might help.

Comment: @fgrieu that stunt is a little funny, no power tolls for Philips screws, the first thing one should apply the cooler even before the screws. Anyway, it is for a demonstration. I'm rather looking on the attacks side and their timing as Halderman et al. did.